# Telerik MVC grid - ArgugumentException when filtering

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-grid

Greetings,

I'm having the problem posted [here](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/the-argument-to-dbisnullexpression-must-refer-to-a-primitive-or-reference-type.aspx) (the post dated August 18th is mine), but not getting anywhere.

In a nutshell, filtering with Telerik's MVC grid causes an ArgumentException with the message "The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive or reference type." Interestingly, if you .ToList() the IQueryable first, you avoid the problem (but pulling back all that data isn't a good solution). Also using Entity Framework and Ajax, not sure if that's an issue or not. Here's the stack trace:

```
System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  Message=The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive or reference type.
  Source=System.Data.Entity
  StackTrace:
       at System.Data.Common.CommandTrees.ExpressionBuilder.Internal.ArgumentValidation.ValidateIsNull(DbExpression argument, Boolean allowRowType)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.CreateIsNullExpression(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression input)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NotTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, UnaryExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.NotEqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.ConditionalTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, ConditionalExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.BinaryTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateIntoCanonicalFunction(String functionName, Expression Expression, Expression[] linqArguments)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.CanonicalFunctionDefaultTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.EqualsTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, BinaryExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateLambda(LambdaExpression lambda, DbExpression input, DbExpressionBinding& binding)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, DbExpression& source, DbExpressionBinding& sourceBinding, DbExpression& lambda)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.OneLambdaTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.AggregateTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.SequenceMethodTranslator.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression call, SequenceMethod sequenceMethod)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.MethodCallTranslator.TypedTranslate(ExpressionConverter parent, MethodCallExpression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TypedTranslator`1.Translate(ExpressionConverter parent, Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.TranslateExpression(Expression linq)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ExpressionConverter.Convert()
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ELinqQueryState.GetExecutionPlan(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetEnumeratorInternal()
       at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.d__b1`1.MoveNext()
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
       at Telerik.Web.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.Count(IQueryable source) in C:\Projects\SoftExposure\Telerik.Web.Mvc\Extensions\QueryableExtensions.cs:line 399
       at Telerik.Web.Mvc.Extensions.QueryableExtensions.ToGridModel(IQueryable queryable, Int32 page, Int32 pageSize, IList`1 sortDescriptors, IEnumerable`1 filterDescriptors, IEnumerable`1 groupDescriptors) in C:\Projects\SoftExposure\Telerik.Web.Mvc\Extensions\QueryableExtensions.cs:line 45
       at Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.GridDataProcessor.EnsureDataSourceIsProcessed() in C:\Projects\SoftExposure\Telerik.Web.Mvc\UI\Grid\GridDataProcessor.cs:line 162
       at Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.GridDataProcessor.get_ProcessedDataSource() in C:\Projects\SoftExposure\Telerik.Web.Mvc\UI\Grid\GridDataProcessor.cs:line 132
       at Telerik.Web.Mvc.GridActionAttribute.OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext filterContext) in C:\Projects\SoftExposure\Telerik.Web.Mvc\UI\Grid\GridActionAttribute.cs:line 104
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.c__DisplayClassd.c__DisplayClassf.b__c()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

and here's the code that causes it

```
        // Note: We need to use a ViewModel rather than the entity directly because the entity relationships
        // will cause a circular reference when used via Ajax.
        // See http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/telerik-ui-components-grid-troubleshooting.html#ServerError
        // 
        private IEnumerable GetCustomers()
        {
            var model = new NorthwindEntities().Customers
                .Select(c => new CustomerModel()
                {
                    CustomerID = c.CustomerID,
                    CompanyName = c.CompanyName,
                    ContactName = c.ContactName
                }); // Call .ToList() here to avoid "The argument to DbIsNullExpression must refer to a primitive or reference type."
                    // when filtering.
                    // See http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/grid/the-argument-to-dbisnullexpression-must-refer-to-a-primitive-or-reference-type.aspx

            return model;
        }
```

Stepping through the source, it's easy to see that it's happening in the QueryableExtensions.Count() method, but the real reason is because of what's happening in the .Where() method when one has filterDescriptors. Whatever the expression building stuff is doing seems to be the cause.

This is the first time I've looked that deeply into expression trees and what not, if anyone can suggest something to try, it's appreciated.

Regards,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

Looking over the thread it seems as if Telerik was not able to reproduce the issue on their end, nor were they able to get a sample project displaying the issue. Did you attempt to package this and send it over to them via their support ticketing system (different than their online forums). I'm sure they'd appreciate getting a hold of something reproducing the issue and you should be able to get a resolution from their support team :)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know they had a ticketing system different than their forums. Did contact them and we'll see how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Telerik was kind enough to open a support ticket (I'm using the free, open source version). Turns out the issue is resolved in the latest drop - 2010.2.825.